# How do I get my ATI 6670 graphics card to work?

Tags: 11.10, ati, graphics, multiple-monitors

I had Ubuntu 11.10 working absolutely fine with my previous (ATI 4870) card and 2 monitors. Unfortunately, after replacing this card with the ATI 6670 and 3 monitors, I've been struggling with getting everything working properly.

Initially, I had a mirrored dispay on all 3 screens but trying to change this with the Catalyst Control (with admin privileges) resulted in the control closing without saving the changes (after clicking on apply).

Therefore, I decided to remove the proprietary drivers to see if the open source ones would work or if reinstalling them would help. I followed the instructions on number 2 of this site: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem:%20%20Need%20to%20fully%20remove%20-fglrx%20and%20reinstall%20-ati%20from%20scratch

After restarting, I can see the Ubuntu loading screen on all 3 but then afterwards I get no display on any of them. After upgrading to 11.10, I also don't see the Grub boot loader any longer so I can't try going into safe mode to make further changes.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tips and problem solutions for the proprietary driver from AMD can you find in the unofficial wiki here: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu

There is a description how you must configure fglrx drivers for multi-monitoring.